# How to insert data into in a table which has a foreign key

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called Customers and Credit cards. I am trying to insert data into the customers table. I got confused how to insert data into customer and it throw an error saying

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

`CreditCards` table

```
CREATE TABLE CreditCards
(
    CreditCardID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    MiddleName NVARCHAR(40),
    LastName NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Brand NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Bank NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    [Number] INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    DateofExpiration DATETIME NOT NULL,
    VerificationCode INT NOT NULL
);
```

`Customer` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    CustomerID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    MiddleName NVARCHAR(40),
    LastName NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    StreetAddress NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [State] NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Country NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    CellPhoneNumber NVARCHAR(40),
    EmailAddress NVARCHAR(120),
    CreditCardID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CreditCards(CreditCardID)
);
```

I am trying to insert data into customer table using this statement

```
INSERT INTO Customers 
VALUES ('John', 'ba', 'Dock', '515 East Halliday Street', 'Idaho', 'United States of America', '2082203814', 'docjon@ss.org');
```

Comment: This looks like MS Sql Server, not MySQL.

Comment: You're missing the `CustomerID` value in your `INSERT` statement. Use `NULL` if you want it to fill it in automatically using the `IDENTITY` feature.

Comment: It also looks like they are also missing a value for CreditCardID.

Comment: ExpirationDate of a credit card is a **DATE**, not a datetime.

Answer (score 1):

This error has nothing to do with foreign keys.

The `Customers` table has 10 columns, but you only have 8 values in your `INSERT` statement. You're missing the `CustomerID` and `CreditCardID` values.

You should list the columns that you're filling in explicitly in the `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (FirstName, MiddleName, LastNamr, StreetAddress, [State] , Country, CellPhoneNumber, EmailAddress)
VALUES('John','ba','Dock','515 East Halliday Street','Idaho','United State of America','2082203814','docjon@ss.org');
```

Columns that you leave out will get their default values; `CustomerID` will be filled in automatically using the `IDENTITY` feature, and `CreditCardID` will be `NULL`. If you want to use the `CreditCardID` of the row that was just inserted into the `CreditCards` table, you can use the `@@IDENTITY` variable:

```
NSERT INTO Customers (FirstName, MiddleName, LastNamr, StreetAddress, [State] , Country, CellPhoneNumber, EmailAddress, CreditCardID)
VALUES('John','ba','Dock','515 East Halliday Street','Idaho','United State of America','2082203814','docjon@ss.org', @@IDENTITY);
```

This is a good idea even when you're providing all columns, since you don't make your statement dependent on the order of the columns in the table creation. It also makes the code easier to understand, since readers don't have to refer back to the table specification to know what each value is.

BTW, you have a typo in one of your column names: `LastNamr` should presumably be `LastName`.

Comment: Thank you for helping out.Is there specific thing i need to do to insert the data of the Creditcard Id

Comment: Use `@@IDENTITY` to get the ID that was just assigned in the most recent insert to that table.

Comment: BTW, if you're in the US, saving the CVV code in your database is a violation of PCI regulations.